# error while cataloging rman backup

Tags: oracle, rman

I'm new in Oracle. When I try to Install Oracle 12c,This Error Appear. How can I fix this?
[error screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYBG3.png)

this is my trace.log error section:

```
[RMANUtil.getRMANUtil:133]   creating new util instance
[RMANUtil.getRMANUtil:134]   target sid orcl
[RMANEngine.getEnvParams:432]  NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
[RMANEngine.initialize:194]  Execing RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:220]  Created RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:234]  Starting Reader Thread... 
[RMANEngine.initialize:238]  Started reader thread for RMAN process in initialize...
[RMANEngine.run:786]  Started reader thread for RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.run:790]  Set m_bReaderStarted  to true  in initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:246]  Started error thread for RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:251]  Created output writer for RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:289]  Created Log writer for RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.initialize:294]  Value of m_bReaderStarted in initialize=true
[RMANEngine.initialize:309]  Made sure reader has started for RMAN process from initialize...
[RMANEngine.connect:758]  NOT using OS auth to connect
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1169]  m_bExecQuery=false
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1177]  Command being written to rman process=connect target SYS/****** 47";
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1205]  Notify reader to start reading
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Jul 1 19:48:29 2018
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN> 
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "integer": expecting one of: "newline, ;"
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 30 file: standard input
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=RMAN> 
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=echo set on
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:872]  Log RMAN Output=set echo off;
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:915]  hasError is true
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:921]  ERROR TRACE DETECTED
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:928]  m_errHdlr=null
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:952]  FATAL ERROR DETECTED
[RMANEngine.readSqlOutput:1016]  Notifying writer to proceed because m_bInterrupted=falsebNotify=truem_bReaderDone=truem_bFatalErrorOccured=true
[RMANEngine.run:800]  Return Value from readSqlOutput=null
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1217]  Completed wait from reader
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1232]  Calling done as got exception
[RMANEngine.done:1537]  Done called
[RMANEngine.executeImpl:1259]  GOT FATAL Error=Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Jul 1 19:48:29 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
RMAN> 
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "integer": expecting one of: "newline, ;"
RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 30 file: standard input
RMAN> 
echo set on
[RMANUtil.catalogBackup:470]  Error while cataloging RMAN Backups: Cannot get RMANUtil
[CloneRmanRestoreStep.executeImpl:475]  exception renaming datafiles oracle.sysman.assistants.util.rmanEngine.RMANFatalErrorException: Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
[BasicStep.configureSettings:347]  messageHandler being set=oracle.sysman.assistants.util.InteractiveMessageHandler@56ee20fe
oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepExecutionException: Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.CloneRmanRestoreStep.executeImpl(CloneRmanRestoreStep.java:476)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:253)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.Step.execute(Step.java:135)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepContext$ModeRunner.run(StepContext.java:2865)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Look in the DBCA logs. There may be some hints there. Find them under `$ORACLE_BASE/cfgtoollogs/dbca`

Comment: So where did that '47' come that is following the sys/password?  Looks like when the setup dialog asked for a password for user SYS, instead of 'mypassword' you keyed in 'mypassword 47'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer
The reason for the error was that there was a space in the password!!!!!!